# How create structured DataDrame from multiples arrays and lists?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm using Python3.
I have three lists, one with the names of distributors of the products, the other with the list of products and another with the classification of the products and finally, I have two arrays.

Each one of the distributors offers 15 products, all of them.

```
distributors = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']
products = ['apple', 'carrot', 'potato', 'avocado', 'pumkie', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'lettuce', 'tomato', 'pees', 'pear', 'berries', 'strawberries', 'blueberries', 'boxes']
tips = ['fruit', 'vegetables', 'random']

actual_prix = np.random.rand(15, 5)
prix_prox_year = np.random.rand(15,5)
```

The structure of the arrays is the following: the rows are the products in order and the columns are the distributors in order.
And the output that I need is the following:

```
       Products  Distributor   Actual      Next_year    Type
    0  apple         d1      0.16147847    0.28173206   fruit
    1    ...        ...        ...          ...         fruit
    2  apple         d5        ...          ...         fruit
   ...   ...        ...        ...          ...          ...
   15  boxes         d5        ...          ...         random
```

This is just an example because my arrays have this size`(1010, 33)`.

Any idea?

Comment: how do you know which distributor is associated with which products?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `product` from itertools to create all of your interactions, the ordering is important to get the pattern of your data. For the arrays you'll need to tile so it's repeated for each element in `tips` and ravel into a single long array so that the length matches.

I changed one of your arrays to be an increasing count that way it's obvious what is going on.

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np

distributors = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']
products = ['apple', 'carrot', 'potato', 'avocado', 'pumkie', 'banana', 
            'kiwi', 'lettuce', 'tomato', 'pees', 'pear', 'berries', 'strawberries', 
            'blueberries', 'boxes']
tips = ['fruit', 'vegetables', 'random']

actual_prix = np.arange(15*5).reshape(15,5)
prix_prox_year = np.random.rand(15,5)
```

---

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd


df = (pd.DataFrame([*product(products, tips, distributors)],
                   columns=['Products', 'Type', 'Distributor'])
        .assign(Actual = np.tile(actual_prix, len(tips)).ravel(),
                Next_year = np.tile(prix_prox_year, len(tips)).ravel()))
```

---

```
print(df)

    Products        Type Distributor  Actual  Next_year
0      apple       fruit          d1       0   0.391903
1      apple       fruit          d2       1   0.378865
2      apple       fruit          d3       2   0.056134
3      apple       fruit          d4       3   0.623146
4      apple       fruit          d5       4   0.879184
5      apple  vegetables          d1       0   0.391903
6      apple  vegetables          d2       1   0.378865
...
219    boxes  vegetables          d5      74   0.804884
220    boxes      random          d1      70   0.900764
221    boxes      random          d2      71   0.455267
222    boxes      random          d3      72   0.489814
223    boxes      random          d4      73   0.054597
224    boxes      random          d5      74   0.804884
```

Comment: a better and more complete answer than mine. Nice work.

Comment: Just one question, what I want is that the apple appears like fruit only, the boxes like random and the lettuce just like a vegetable, I mean, that row should classify the object in that three categories. I did a dictionary but I don't know how to do it now for have the column type like I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools and set functions to get the unique combinations and then put it into a dataframe.

```
import itertools
store = ["a", "b", "c"]
prods = ['apple', 'banana']

all_combinations = [list(zip(each_permutation, prods)) for each_permutation in itertools.permutations(store, len(prods))]
```